# Why would we want parallelizable authentication?

Tags: authentication, hmac, authenticated-encryption

I believe that parallelizable authentication schemes are superior from an aesthetic perspective and because most non-recursive calculations (e.g., CTR, ECB, PMAC, etc.) are better than recursive ones (e.g., CBC, OFB, CFB, CBC-MAC, etc.).

Most of the CAESAR candidates, i.e. GCM, OCB mode, PMAC, XOR-MACs, and protected counter sum provide parallelizable authentication while HMAC is not parallelizable.

One paper out there says that many schemes used by the CAESAR candidates, GCM, and XOR-MACs can be trivially broken by an incredibly unrealistic quantum attack (it turns the complexity from $O(2^{n})$ to $O(n)$ but requires a quantum entangled state that can only be generated with the key). Additionally, with or without quantum computers, many of these parallelizable authentication schemes only provide security up the birthday bound.  This makes it seem like a lot of the known parallelizable modes of authentication are not as strong as an HMAC construction.

Am I mistaken? Is there anything about most particular parallelizable methods that have drawbacks/weaknesses relative to HMACs? If so, what are they? And why do we seek parallelizable methods if that is the case?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a vector unit on your CPU that can be used only by a single thread at a time but remains powered whether you're using it or not, it takes less time, and is therefore cheaper, to compute a parallelizable function using the entire vector unit than to compute nonparallelizable function using only a part of the vector unit.

If you have only three cycles per byte to spare in your computing budget, there is no way you will fit HMAC-SHA256 in that.  But you can easily fit Poly1305.  The more parallelizable the function, the more flexibility you have to adapt it to vector units of different sizes to maximize throughput subject to your power constraints.

The alleged quantum threat to these constructions posits the asinine model where the legitimate user reveals quantum superpositions of secret function evaluations to the adversary.  If you do your cryptography on a classical computer on ordinary bits, then the model is irrelevant.  If, under the currently unrealistic premise that quantum computers were actually capable of it, you did your cryptography on a quantum computer and enabled this attack model, you would be an idiot.  This model gives amusing theoretical results, but it is totally irrelevant to the real world.

Comment: This model does show that it is impossible to create a quantum-safe white-box implementation of GCM.  Other than that, I agree that it is irrelevant to the real world...

Comment: Indeed.  It remains unclear, of course, whether it's even possible to create a _classical_-safe white-box implementation of AES-GCM!

Comment: Or if it's possible to make a whitebox implementation of anything symmetric; attempts at whitebox AES tended to be unexpected easy to break.  However, it *might* be possible in most cases, in the postquantum GCM case, we know that's not the case...

Comment: So this attack model is similar to giving an adversary DSA signatures that use the same per-message value?

Comment: @Melab More like a quantum superposition of DSA signatures on an attacker-specified quantum superposition of messages, under a single per-signature secret.  A classical set is not the same as a quantum superposition, but a quantum superposition is definitely a lot more information than a single value.

Comment: What I mean is are they similar in that there is no reason you might need to do either (reuse a per-signature value or give someone a quantum superpositions of secret function evaluations)?

Comment: And why does the attack make whitebox implementations of any of the susceptible algorithms impossible?

Comment: @Melab Yes: reusing a per-signature secret _or_ handing the adversary a quantum superposition of secret function evaluations will absolutely void the security contract of DSA or just about anything else.  A whitebox implementation is a public circuit for evaluating a secret function, _e.g._ $x \mapsto \operatorname{AES}_k(x)$ for some secret $k$, that a quantum-capable adversary could compile into a quantum circuit and evaluate in quantum superposition themselves on their quantum computer.  The idea is to conceal $k$.  The attack shows that a quantum adversary can learn $k$ anyway.

Comment: How is that any different from having knowledge of pairs of plaintext and ciphertext blocks? That would make any symmetric cipher vulnerable to a known-plaintext attack. Does this mean that keys secured in tamper-proof silicon, like an iPhone/iPad's UID and GID keys, can be recovered as just easily?

Comment: @Melab Does the tamper-proof silicon in your iPhone perform quantum computation and return quantum superpositions of outputs given a quantum superpositions of inputs?  Or does it return a single output for each single input given to it?  Obviously, if you could enumerate all the possible inputs, you could break any cryptosystem built out of this gadget, but there are too many for you to enumerate one by one.  (Hint: If you knew how to make a quantum computer scale large enough to compute AES, I assure you there are more exciting applications than making cryptographically defective iPhones.)

Comment: You said, without qualification, that the quantum attack in question makes whitebox implementations impossible.